# Problem with inserting and updating main video in database in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project for ads/properties in Laravel. I have gallery of multiple videos for each individual ad. I want to be able to select one of those videos with radio button and make it primary video for that ad (show that particular video next to ad). I have has many relationship between property and video and I am trying to insert id of video from videos table to main_video_id column in properties table and also when I change current video for new one to update that foreign key accordingly. I am having trouble to write that method in my controller. Any help is appreciated. Here are my tables and code.

```
properties (id, title, location, price, main_video_id)

videos (id, filename_video, model_id)
```

In videos table model_id column is foreign key that connects to properties table.

PropertyController.php

```
public function edit(Property $property, Request $request)
{
    if (!($property->user_id == Auth::user()->id)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $category = $property->category;

    foreach ($property->photos as $value) {
        $photoarray[] = $value->filename;
    };

    empty($photoarray) ? $photo = '' : $photo = implode(",", $photoarray);

    foreach ($property->videos as $value1) {
        $videoArray[] = $value1->filename_video;
    };

    empty($videoArray) ? $video = '' : $video = implode(",", $videoArray);


    $data = .... Here I am having trouble writing method!


    return view('property.edit', compact(
        'category',
        'photo',
        'property',
        'video', 
        'data'
    ));
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form id="form" action="/property/{{$property->id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="hideninput" data-src="property/{{$property->id}}/gallery"value="{{old('video',$video)}}" name="video">
    @if (old('video', $video))
    @foreach (array_filter(explode(',',old('video', $video)), 'strlen') as $key =>$value)
        <div id="{{'div_video_'.$key}}" class="col-md-3" style="padding: 15px;">

            @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="{{ $value->video_id }}">Make main
            @endforeach

            <button data="{{$key}}" type="button" class="closebuttonvideo">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <video id="{{'video_'.$key}}" data={{$value}} src="/storage/property/{{$property->id}}/gallery/{{$value}}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{"inactivityTimeout": 0}' width="180" height="180">
            </video>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
```

Property.php

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class, 'model_id');
}
```

Video.php

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
```

Comment: You have to set your requested id in data field like this: `$data = request->input('radio')`, After that you will have a requested default video `id` in your var, and update the model with this id, return refreshed view.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I get the idea just can't put it to code. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `main_video_id` in the `properties` table, I would go with the following approach:

Add a column `is_main_video` to `videos` table and a composite unique constraint as below:

```php
$table->boolean('is_main_video')->nullable()->default(null);
$table->unique(['model_id', 'is_main_video']);
```

> The unique constraint ensures that there are no multiple main videos for a single property.

In `Property.php`

```php
protected $appends = ['mainVideo'];

public function videos()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Video::class, 'model_id');
}

public function getMainVideoAttribute()
{
    return $this->videos->first(function($video) {
         return $video->is_main_vide;
    });
}
```

Now when you fetch `properties`, you'll automatically get the `mainVideo` and related videos as a result as show below:

```
array:4 [
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "property 1"
  "mainVideo" => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "model_id" => 1
    "is_main_video" => 1
    "name" => "Video 2"
  ]
  "videos" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "model_id" => 1
      "is_main_video" => null
      "name" => "Video 1"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "id" => 2
      "model_id" => 1
      "is_main_video" => 1
      "name" => "Video 2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And how should I procede now in my view and my controller?

Comment: Was it helpful @Marko ?

Comment: Solved it with different approach. But thank you anyway :)